# How to calculate moving average using pandas for a daily frequency over 3 years

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a large dataset and need to calculate rolling returns over 3 years for each date. I am new in pandas and not able to understand that how can I do this using pandas. Below is my sample data frame.

```
       nav_date     price
1989  2019-11-29    25.02
2338  2019-11-28    25.22
1991  2019-11-27    25.11
1988  2019-11-26    24.98
1990  2019-11-25    25.06
1978  2019-11-22    24.73
1984  2019-11-21    24.84
1985  2019-11-20    24.90
1980  2019-11-19    24.78
1971  2019-11-18    24.67
1975  2019-11-15    24.69
1970  2019-11-14    24.64
1962  2019-11-13    24.58
1977  2019-11-11    24.73
1976  2019-11-08    24.72
1987  2019-11-07    24.93
1983  2019-11-06    24.84
1979  2019-11-05    24.74
1981  2019-11-04    24.79
1974  2019-11-01    24.68
2337  2019-10-31    24.66
1966  2019-10-30    24.59
1957  2019-10-29    24.47
1924  2019-10-25    24.06
2336  2019-10-24    24.06
1929  2019-10-23    24.10
1923  2019-10-22    24.05
1940  2019-10-18    24.20
1921  2019-10-17    24.05
1890  2019-10-16    23.77
1882  2019-10-15    23.70
1868  2019-10-14    23.52
1860  2019-10-11    23.45
1846  2019-10-10    23.30
1862  2019-10-09    23.46
2335  2019-10-07    23.08
1837  2019-10-04    23.18
1863  2019-10-03    23.47
1873  2019-10-01    23.57
1894  2019-09-30    23.80
1901  2019-09-27    23.88
1916  2019-09-26    24.00
1885  2019-09-25    23.73
1919  2019-09-24    24.04
1925  2019-09-23    24.06
1856  2019-09-20    23.39
1724  2019-09-19    22.22
1773  2019-09-18    22.50
1763  2019-09-17    22.45
1811  2019-09-16    22.83
1825  2019-09-13    22.98
1806  2019-09-12    22.79
1817  2019-09-11    22.90
1812  2019-09-09    22.84
1797  2019-09-06    22.72
1777  2019-09-05    22.52
1776  2019-09-04    22.51
2334  2019-09-03    22.42
1815  2019-08-30    22.88
1798  2019-08-29    22.73
1820  2019-08-28    22.93
1830  2019-08-27    23.05
1822  2019-08-26    22.95
1770  2019-08-23    22.48
1737  2019-08-22    22.30
1794  2019-08-21    22.66
2333  2019-08-20    22.86
1821  2019-08-19    22.93
1819  2019-08-16    22.92
1814  2019-08-14    22.88
```

However I can do this in simple python but it takes too long to execute. In python I do like this-

```
start_date = '2019-10-31'
end_date = '2016-10-31' #For 3 years
years = 3

# Now look at each price for all the dates between start_date and end_date for 3 year and #calculate the CAGR and then do the average.

total_returns = 0
for n in range(int((start_date - end_date).days)):
    sd = start_date - relativedelta(days=n)
    ed = sd - relativedelta(years=years)
    returns = (((price_dict['sd']/price_dict['ed']) ** (1 / years)) - 1) * 100
    total_returns+=returns
roll_return = total_returns/int((start_date - end_date).days)
```

I am sure there will be something to get the same output using pandas without making too much iteration since it is getting too slow and takes too much time to execute. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add expected output?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar: Let's say 2019-11-29 is my starting date then I need to calculate CAGR for 3 years so that for each day till 2016-11-29. 
price for 2019-11-29 = 25.02 
price for 2016-11-29 = 26.50 
CAGR = (((25.02/26.50) ** (1 /3)) - 1) * 100 = -68.53 similarly for each date till 2016-11-29 so the next would be- 
price for 2019-11-28 = 25.02 
price for 2016-11-28 = 26.50 
CAGR = (((25.02/26.50) ** (1 /3)) - 1) * 100 = -68.53
finaloutput will be the average of all calculated CAGR

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show expected result... In any case, this is just an example and I think you'll understand my approach.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'nav_date': (
        '2019-11-29',
        '2018-11-29',
        '2017-11-29',
        '2016-11-29',
        '2019-11-28',
        '2018-11-28',
        '2017-11-28',
        '2016-11-28',
    ),
    'price': (
        25.02,  # <- example of your price(2019-11-29)
        25.11,
        25.06,
        26.50,  # <- example of your price(2016-11-29)
        30.51,
        30.41,
        30.31,
        30.21,
    ),
})


df['year'] = ''
# parse year from date string
df['year'] = df['nav_date'].apply(lambda x: x[0:4])
# parse date without year
df['nav_date'] = df['nav_date'].apply(lambda x: x[5:])
# years to columns, prices to rows
df = df.pivot(index='nav_date', columns='year', values='price')
df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_records())
# value calculation by columns...
df['2019'] = ((df['2019'] / df['2016'] * (1 / 3)) - 1) * 100
# df['2018'] = blablabla...
print(df)
```

Result:

```
  nav_date   2016   2017   2018       2019
0    11-28  30.21  30.31  30.41 -66.335650
1    11-29  26.50  25.06  25.11 -68.528302  # <- your expected value
```

So you'll have `dataframe` with calculated values by each day and you can easily do anything with it(`avg()`/`max()`/`min()`/just any manipulations).

Hope this helps.